# abstractmethod decorator to all methods in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, abc

I tried to make my realization where i don't need to use all times to all methods decorator `@abstractmethod`

Firstly, i realize class decorator, but this don't need any result:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


def interface(cls):
   for attr in cls.__dict__:
      if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
         setattr(cls, attr, abstractmethod(getattr(cls, attr)))
    
   return cls


@interface
class A(ABC):
   def foo(self):
      pass

   def bar(self):
      pass


class B(A):
   def foo(self):
      pass

b = B()
```

Secondly, i tried make it in `__init__` method in class and it's don't give any result too:

```
class Interface(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        for attr in self.__dict__:
            attr_obj = getattr(self, attr)

            if callable(attr_obj):
                setattr(self, attr, abstractmethod(attr_obj))

class A(Interface):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

   def foo(self):
      pass

   def bar(self):
      pass


class B(A):
   def foo(self):
      pass


b = B()
```

How can i realize a way where all methods in class decorated with `@abstractmethod`?

Comment: I believe the implemention of ABC relies on metaclass magic that require the methods be decorated before the metaclass is instantiated (i.e. in the class body. .). By the time your decorator has the instantiated class object, it is too late. You could try creating a *copy* of the class with the methods appropriately decorated before they are passed along with the class namespace to the metaclass constructor. Seems dicey though. I would just bite the bullet.

Comment: Your second approach will not work, `self.__dict__` is *the instance namespace* it doesn't contain methods. And again, by now it is too late for `ABCMeta` to do anything

Comment: Why not use a static type checking with `mypy` and structural subtyping with `Protocol`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You can circumvent a metaclass' magic by overriding the `__new__` method of the metaclass and altering the class members before the original metaclass' `__new__` method is called.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better approach to avoid decorating methods of child classes with `abstractmethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @juanpa.arrivillaga mentions, it's too late to decorate an abstract class after the class is instantiated since `ABC` alters its class members with its metaclass, `ABCMeta`.

Instead, you can subclass `ABCMeta` (as `Interface` in the example below) and perform modifications to the `classdict` parameter of the class constructor *before* calling the constructor of the superclass.

Since child classes are supposed to implement abstract methods by default and not continue to declare methods abstract in typical cases, you should avoid decorating methods of child classes with `abstractmethod`, but since child classes would inherit the metaclass of the parent, you would have to explicitly make the constructor of the `Interface` return an object of `ABCMeta` instead of `Interface` itself so that the custom behavior would not be inherited:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Interface(ABCMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, classdict):
        for attr, value in classdict.items():
            if callable(value):
                classdict[attr] = abstractmethod(value)
        return super().__new__(ABCMeta, name, bases, classdict)
```

so that:

```
class A(metaclass=Interface):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass

b = B()
```

would produce:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract method bar
```

while:

```
class A(metaclass=Interface):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass
```

would run with no error.